# Update fetched data using a response from different api request using React Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have a data which is displayed in a table, this data is fetched using react query. I have table headers and when i click on these i want it to, fetch a different api request, to get ordered data then update the original data with this new fetched data.

**/Code**

```
//Api 

export const GetEnrolled = async () => {
    const response = await MemberApi.get(`query?orderBy=FirstName&order=DESC&pageSize=1&status=Enrolled`);
    return response.data;
};

export const GetFilterQuery = async (filter, order, status) => {
    const response = await MemberApi.get(`/query?orderBy=${filter}&order=${order}&pageNumber=1&pageSize=50&status=${status}`);
    return response.data;
};
```

```
//Members

function Members(){
    const {data: enrolled} = useQuery({queryKey: ["enrolled"], queryFn: () => GetEnrolled()});

    function UpdateData() {
     queryClient.setQueryData(["enrolled"], data = GetFilterQuery("LastName","DESC","Enrolled"));
    }

    return (
    <>
        <button onClick={() => UpdateData()}>Update<button/>
        {enrolled.map(member => {
           return (
            <div>
                {member.firstName}
            <div/>)
        })}
    </>
    )


}
```